# Is there a way to avoid loops while instancing SQLAlchemy ORM objects?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I am currently using SQLAlchemy CORE to collect data from some heterogenous databases, run some calculations and then write the data in a new database using SQLAlchemy ORM model.
Here is the time breakdown:

Start   --   2022-06-27 13:53:50.967981
End B3DB Init   --   0:00:02.276641
End CORE Read   --   0:00:00.686167
End Calculations   --   0:00:00.577456
End DADODB Init   --   0:00:00.063829
End ORM Instancing   --   0:00:03.511613
End DADODB Commit   --   0:00:01.050192
Total   --   0:00:08.165898

The most time costly phase is looping through the 1K rows approximately of data to be inserted.

There are two tables and this is what I'm doing:

```
undrl_asset = Asset(
            timestamp  = datetime.now(),
            tradedate  = tgtdate,
            trckrsymb  = undrl_ticker,
            openprice  = undrl_data.iloc[0]['UNDRL_PREABE'],
            maxprice   = undrl_data.iloc[0]['UNDRL_PREMAX'],
            minprice   = undrl_data.iloc[0]['UNDRL_PREMIN'],
            avgprice   = undrl_data.iloc[0]['UNDRL_PREMED'],
            lastprice  = undrl_data.iloc[0]['UNDRL_PREULT'],
            buyoffer   = undrl_data.iloc[0]['UNDRL_PREOFC'],
            selloffer  = undrl_data.iloc[0]['UNDRL_PREOFV'],
            numdeals   = int(undrl_data.iloc[0]['UNDRL_TOTNEG']),
            totamnt    = int(undrl_data.iloc[0]['UNDRL_QUATOT']),
            totcash    = undrl_data.iloc[0]['UNDRL_VOLTOT'],
            vh         = pd.to_numeric(undrl_data.iloc[0]['UNDRL_VH'])
)



for i in range(num_calls):

this_option = Derivative(
    
            timestamp  = datetime.now(),  
            tradedate  = tgtdate,  
            trckrsymb  = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_TRCKR_SYMB'],    
            undrlasst  = undrl_ticker,  
            sgmntname  = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_SEGMENT'],    
            expirdate  = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_EXP_DATE'],  
            exrcprice  = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_STRIKE'],  
            optnstyle  = str(call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_STYLE'])[0:1],
            mrktprice  = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_PREULT'] if call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_PREULT'] > 0 else None,
            dayqntneg  = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_VLMNEG'] if call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_VLMNEG'] > 0 else None,  
            cvrdpos    = int(call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_COVERED']),  
            blkspos    = int(call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_BLOCKD']),  
            uncvpos    = int(call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_UNCOVRD']),  
            totlpos    = int(call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_TOT_OI']),  
            holdqty    = int(call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_TITULRS']),  
            writqty    = int(call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_LANCDRS']),  
            iq         = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_TITULRS']/call_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_LANCDRS'], 
            timtoexp   = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_TIME_TO_EXP'],  
            moneynes   = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_MNYNS'], 
            impldvol   = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_IV'] if call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_IV'] > 0 else None,  
            polycofa   = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_P_A'],  
            polycofb   = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_P_B'],  
            polycofc   = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_P_C'],  
            chosnvol   = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_VOL'],  
            optdelta   = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_DELTA'],  
            optgamma   = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_GAMMA'],
            optpctgm   = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_PCT_GAMMA'],
            opttheta   = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_THETA'],  
            optbgt     = call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_BGT'] if call_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_BGT'] > 0 else None,  
            totdelta   = int(call_raw_data.iloc[i]['TOT_DELTA']),  
            totgamma   = int(call_raw_data.iloc[i]['TOT_GAMMA']),  
            ttpctgmm   = int(call_raw_data.iloc[i]['TOT_PCT_GAMMA']),  
            tottheta   = int(call_raw_data.iloc[i]['TOT_THETA']),  
            totbgt     = int(call_raw_data.iloc[i]['TOT_BGT'])    

)

options_array.append(this_option)   

for i in range(num_puts):

this_option = Derivative(
    
            timestamp  = datetime.now(),  
            tradedate  = tgtdate,  
            trckrsymb  = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_TRCKR_SYMB'],    
            undrlasst  = undrl_ticker,  
            sgmntname  = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_SEGMENT'],    
            expirdate  = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_EXP_DATE'],  
            exrcprice  = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_STRIKE'],  
            mrktprice  = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_PREULT'] if put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_PREULT'] > 0 else None ,
            dayqntneg  = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_VLMNEG'] if put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_VLMNEG'] > 0 else None ,  
            cvrdpos    = int(put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_COVERED']),  
            blkspos    = int(put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_BLOCKD']),  
            uncvpos    = int(put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_UNCOVRD']),  
            totlpos    = int(put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_TOT_OI']),  
            holdqty    = int(put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_TITULRS']),  
            writqty    = int(put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_LANCDRS']),   
            iq         = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_TITULRS']/put_raw_data.iloc[i]['OPT_LANCDRS'], 
            timtoexp   = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_TIME_TO_EXP'],  
            moneynes   = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_MNYNS'], 
            impldvol   = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_IV'] if put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_IV'] > 0 else None,  
            polycofa   = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_P_A'],  
            polycofb   = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_P_B'],  
            polycofc   = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_P_C'],  
            chosnvol   = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_VOL'],  
            optdelta   = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_DELTA'],  
            optgamma   = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_GAMMA'],
            optpctgm   = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_PCT_GAMMA'],
            opttheta   = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_THETA'],  
            optbgt     = put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_BGT'] if put_raw_data.iloc[i]['CALC_BGT'] > 0 else None,  
            totdelta   = int(put_raw_data.iloc[i]['TOT_DELTA']),  
            totgamma   = int(put_raw_data.iloc[i]['TOT_GAMMA']),  
            ttpctgmm   = int(put_raw_data.iloc[i]['TOT_PCT_GAMMA']),  
            tottheta   = int(put_raw_data.iloc[i]['TOT_THETA']),  
            totbgt     = int(put_raw_data.iloc[i]['TOT_BGT'])      

)

options_array.append(this_option)
```

Is there a way to declare the ORM object or code the object instancing in a vectorized manner, avoiding the loops creating new instances?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the majority of the time consumed is not due to the loops *per se*, but the effort required to construct the instances of the ORM objects. Using ORM objects is often not the best approach for bulk loading data. You might save some time by adjusting the column names in your DataFrames to match the column names in the tables for each of your ORM objects and then using `dataframe.to_sql(…, if_exists="append")`

Comment: @GordThompson thanks for the formatting on the original question and for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Gord's suggestion and that indeed did the trick.

Start   --   2022-06-29 14:44:00.847775

End B3DB Init   --   0:00:02.259717

End CORE Read   --   0:00:00.485671

End Calculations   --   0:00:00.582443

End DADODB Init   --   0:00:00.056849

End ORM Instancing   --   0:00:03.634285

End DADODB Commit   --   0:00:00.963426

End DF.to_sql() Commit   --   0:00:00.206448

Total   --   0:00:08.188839

Starting with the data in a dataframe, putting it into ORM instances and writing would take roughly 4.5s. Just running the DF.to_SQL() method gets it done in 0.21s.